# python logging don't catch exceptions

Tags: python, exception, logging, websocket

When I try and use python's logging module, it seems to catch exceptions and print out an error instead of allowing the program to crash normally.

To initialize the logging I have this:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Now I get all of my info and warning messages, but in addition to this, it appears that when an error occurs it gets caught and printed as an 'error' log message:

```
ERROR:root:'bool' object is not iterable
```

This causes two problems on my end:

1. I can't see the stack trace.
2. The program keeps on executing.

Is there a way to disable this behaviour so that the program crashes with a stack trace as if I didn't have logging enabled?

**Edit**

I'm an idiot. It wasn't the logging that was catching the exceptions. It was the websocket-client module. More specifically, these lines:

```
     except Exception, e:
        self._run_with_no_err(self.on_error, e)

def _run_with_no_err(self, callback, *args):
    if callback:
        try:
            callback(self, *args)
        except Exception, e:
            if logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG):
                logger.error(e)
```

It just so happened that I noticed this behavior when I enabled the logging and didn't think the two were connected.

Comment: can you paste some code located next to this logged error?

Comment: this is not normal behaviour, a simple test program exits as expected here. are you surelysure you're not catching these errors somewhere in your program?

Comment: Are you using logging from standard library?

Comment: logger won't try to catch exception for you, the ERROR log must be from one of your or 3rd party's exception handlers.

Comment: What error do you get when you DO NOT use the logging library? Is there a stack trace there? If so, post it here. Also as @yedpodtrzitko says, some code would be helpful.

Comment: You configured the logging handler, now whatever catches the exception is no longer outputting the exception because you changed the configuration. You need to figure out what happened before, without you configuring the logging handler. The exceptions were already being caught.

Comment: Ya'll are right, but Jaux was the most right. It was the websocket module doing the catching. Thanks!!